# Elasticsearch nested match query returns no results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not new to ElasticSearch but this seemingly simple query is returning zero results, which is baffling.  Elastic version 7.10.2.

**Mapping:**

```
{
    "test-index-v43": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "addresses": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "address": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "aliases": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "alias_name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "identities": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "identity": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `aliases` array is the only one that really matters in this question, but wanted to give the full mapping in case that's lending to the problem.

**Query:**

```
GET test-index-v43/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "aliases",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "aliases.alias_name": "Joseph Shmoseph"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No results are returned, but this document exists in the index, so I don't understand why it doesn't return:

```
  {
    "_index" : "test-index-v43",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1234",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "alias_name" : "Joseph Shmoseph",
      "address" : {
        "houseNumber" : "123",
        "road" : "Main St.",
        "city" : "New York City",
        "postCode" : "12345-6789",
        "country" : "USA"
      }
    }
  }
```

I must be missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The index data given in the question does not follow the format of the index mapping defined. There is no `aliases` field name (that is defined as of `nested` type).**

Since the data that you have indexed, does not have `aliases` as a nested path, so when you are trying to run the search query with `"path": "aliases"`, it does not show any result.

Search Query will not throw any error, as you have already defined `aliases` as of nested type in the index mapping.

Elasticsearch uses dynamic mapping to define the new fields (that are added when indexing new documents), if no index mapping is defined, if you run the below search query, you will get your results

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "alias_name": "Joseph Shmoseph"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Otherwise, you need to index the data in the following format

```
{
  "aliases": {
    "alias_name": "Joseph Shmoseph"
  }
}
```

Now running the same search query (as shown in the question) gives the below result

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67235408",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "aliases": {
            "alias_name": "Joseph Shmoseph"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```